# sed/awk replace a specific pattern under another pattern

Tags: sed, awk

So I have a file like so

```
[ABC]
value1=bla
value2=bla
value3=bla
[XYZ]
value1=bla
value2=bla
value3=bla
```

And I would like to replace the value1 under the [ABC] block with "value1=notbla" and not under the [XYZ] block. I've already tried

```
sed '/ABC/{n;s/.*/change/}'  file
```

But that would only work when trying to go to the next line and would not change the specific pattern (ie. if value1 was under value 2)
What sed or awk command could I use if I didn't know the specific line numbers.
And can you please label the function of each sed or awk tag used. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sed a range of lines?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76105/how-to-sed-a-range-of-lines)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sed can handle this quite easily.  It's a single "substitute" command, prefixed with an address range.  I've added extra spacing for better readability:

```
sed -e '/^\[ABC\]$/ , /^\[.*\]$/     s/^\(value1=\).*$/\1notbla/'
```

Without the extra spacing, it's:

```
sed -e '/^\[ABC\]$/,/^\[.*\]$/s/^\(value1=\).*$/\1notbla/'
```

You don't really need anchored regexes, but they may be safer in some cases of unusual inputs.  A slightly shorter version with unanchored regexes is:

```
sed -e '/\[ABC\]/,/^\[/s/^\(value1=\).*$/\1notbla/'
```

---

## Explanation:

You asked for each flag or option to be explained, and I've got the time, so here you go.  I'm explaining the final (shortest) version out of the three Sed commands listed above.

The first part of the line is an address range: `/startregex/,/stopregex/`  The `s`ubstitute command which follows the address range is only applied to lines from `startregex` to `stopregex` (inclusive).

In this case the start regex is `/\[ABC\]/`.  Square brackets are usually special characters within a regex, so we put a backslash before each to signify literal square bracket characters.

The stop regex is `/^\[/`, which uses the special regex character `^` to signify the start of a line.  This pattern will match any line that starts with a literal left square bracket (`[`).

The `s`ubstitute command is basically quite simple; the general format is `s/findregex/replacetext/`.  It can also have special flags placed after the final `/` to modify its behavior, but I'm not using any such flags here.

The "find regex" is `^\(value1=\).*$`.

The caret (`^`) matches the start of the line, as mentioned earlier, and the dollar sign (`$`) matches the end of the line.  So this whole pattern must match an entire line, not merely part of one.

The parentheses (`()`), unlike square brackets, are *non*-special by default in regexes, so we put the backslashes before them to give them their special meaning.  They allow parts of the matched text (the text matched by the "find regex") to be used in the replacement text.  Specifically, the `\1` in the replacement text means, "The text matched within the first set of parentheses in the regex."  In this case, that is always just "value1=".

The final element in the "find regex" is `.*`.  The dot (`.`) means "any single character," and the asterisk (`*`) means "any number of times (zero or more)."  So the dot star (`.*`) matches the entire rest of the line, after the equals sign.

"notbla" in the replacement text is just static text, nothing special about it.

---

To really learn Sed properly, I highly recommend the [Grymoire Sed tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html), which is free online.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '
  BEGIN {FS=OFS="=";}
  /\[.*\]/ {if ($0 == "[ABC]") edit=1; else edit=0;}
  {if (edit && $1 == "value1" ) $2="notbla";}1
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

another `awk` solution

```
$ cat ip.txt 
[ABC]
value1=bla
value2=bla
value3=bla
[XYZ]
value1=bla
value2=bla
value3=bla
```

If line starts with `[` assign a flag which will be set or cleared based on block name. Then if the flag is set, do the substitution

```
$ awk '/^\[/{f=/\[ABC\]/} f{sub("value1=bla","value1=nobla")} 1' ip.txt 
[ABC]
value1=nobla
value2=bla
value3=bla
[XYZ]
value1=bla
value2=bla
value3=bla
```

Similar solution in `perl`, changed the substitution for demonstration

```
$ perl -pe '$f=/\[ABC\]/ if /^\[/; s/value2=bla/value2=nobla/ if $f;' ip.txt 
[ABC]
value1=bla
value2=nobla
value3=bla
[XYZ]
value1=bla
value2=bla
value3=bla
```

If everything to right of `=` has to be changed regardless of specifically matching to `bla`, use

```
awk '/^\[/{f=/\[ABC\]/} f{sub(/value1=.*/,"value1=nobla")} 1' ip.txt 
perl -pe '$f=/\[ABC\]/ if /^\[/; s/value2=.*/value2=nobla/ if $f;' ip.txt
```