# format output of xdotool window geometry

Tags: awk, sed, regular-expression

I have the following `xdotool` output from the shell:

```
Window 98566146
  Position: 5,279 (screen: 0)
  Geometry: 960x480
```

I want it to be :

```
 x=5
 y=279
 width=960
 height=480
```

with awk, sed, or other tools.

CLARIFICATION: I want to format  output of `xdotool search --sync --class mpv getwindowgeometry` the way I described above using regular expression replace techniques via awk, sed or other tools. There is an example in the following link [sed/awk replace a specific pattern under another pattern](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/315062/sed-awk-replace-a-specific-pattern-under-another-pattern).

Such as

```
echo -e "Window 98566146\n  Position: 5,279 (screen: 0)\n  Geometry: 960x480\n" | awk ....
```

EDIT2:

Actually I could try the following awk line:

```
  echo -e "Window 98566146\n  Position: 5,279 (screen: 0)\n  Geometry: 960x480\n" |  awk -F'[:]' '{if (NR>1) print $2}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this.  Here's a really basic method:

```
$ awk -F'[:,x]' '/Position:/ { sub(" .*","",$3); printf "x=%i\ny=%s\n", $2,$3};
                 /Geometry:/ { printf "width=%i\nheight=%i\n", $2, $3}' xdotool.txt 
x=5
y=279
width=960
height=480
```

This uses either a colon, a comma, or an `x` as the field separator.  It also uses `sub()` to remove the space character and everything after it from the y value ($3) on the Position: line.

`xdotool.txt` is a text file that contains your example xdotool output.

Comment: If you use `y=%d` instead of `y=%s` then you don't need the `sub(" .*","",$3);` since awk will strip everything after the leading numeric part anyway in the process of converting `$3` from a string to a number for printing with `%d`.

Comment: I like to do things explicitly rather than rely on side-effects.  especially when i'm trying to teach someone how to do something. side-effects are a potential source of confusion that just create distracting questions that detract from what is being taught.

Comment: Sounds good, then you should add `sub(/ /,"",$2)` to the Geometry line to explicitly strip the blank from the front of `$2` that THAT conversion to a number (for `%i` ) is currently stripping as a side-effect.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -v RS= -F'[[:space:]:,x]+' '{printf "x=%d\ny=%d\nwidth=%d\nheight=%d\n", $4, $5, $9, $10}' file
x=5
y=279
width=960
height=480
```

Comment: Perfect use of `RS` and `FS` for getting the 4 fields!

Comment: @ed-morton Thank you for your help. Yours is the simplistic approach. I used your liner in my project here https://github.com/trappedinspacetime/mpv-save-window-position/blob/main/save-pos

Comment: @kenn you're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it with this somewhat rudimentary approach, using `tr` and relying on shell word splitting:

```
$ alias XDR='echo -e "Window 98566146\n  Position: 5,279 (screen: 0)\n  Geometry: 960x480\n"'
$ XDR | tr -dc '0-9 ,x' | tr ' ,x' ' '
```

which returns

```
98566146   5 279  0   960 480
```

then just feed it to the shell - I'd suggest using ( ) to protect the current environment:

```
$ (set $(XDR | tr -dc '0-9 ,x' | tr ' ,x' ' ') &&\
   echo -e "x=$2\ny=$3\nwidth=$5\nheight=$6")
```

or in bash, use process substitution to pull it directly into variables:

```
$ read wid x y scr width height < <(XDR | tr -dc '0-9 ,x' | tr ' ,x' ' ')
$ echo -e "x=$x\ny=$y\nwidth=$width\nheight=$height"
```

**update** - the following works just as well:

```
$ XDR | tr -c '0-9' ' '
```

Comment: I just tried it, it works. I like creative ideas. I didn't expect such an innovative approach though I sensed it intuitively. Thank you.

Comment: I've sensed I miss something, it can be done with only one simple tr:
tr -c 0-9 ' '

Comment: Can you please explain your inventive approach? Especially the use of the te utility.

Comment: I'd suggest running tr --help, all you need to know about it is there. One of the simplest, yet most useful tools at hand on any posix console. Play around with it. Do ls -l / | tr a-z A-Z, then do ls -l / | tr -d a-z, or something like ls -l / | tr -cd 'a-z\n'. You'll get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this using `awk` can be firstly, setting `FS` for getting the data of interest into a field, $2 in this case:

```
awk -F'^ +Position: |^ +Geometry: |[()]'  'NR>1{print $2}' file
5,279
960x480
```

Secondly, we can split the data records `2` and `3` with  `split()` function and print them adding the prefixes you need:

```
awk -F'^ +Position: |^ +Geometry: |[()]'  '
   NR == 2 {split($2, a, /,/);print "x="a[1]"\ny="a[2]}
   NR == 3 {split($2, a, /x/);print "width="a[1]"\nheight="a[2]}
' file
x=5
y=279
width=960
height=480
```

Comment: My knowledge of `awk` is basic. I didn't know how to replace text. AWK is a treasure. Your answer is detailed. Thank you.

Comment: You are right, `awk is a treasure`, sometimes easy and sometimes not so, but always efficient for managing text. I learn something every day I use it.

Answer (score 1):

Tested with `GNU sed` and `busybox sed`:

```
sed -nEe 's/^[[:space:]]+Position: ([[:digit:]]+),([[:digit:]]+) \(screen: 0\)$/x=\1\ny=\2/p' -e 's/^[[:space:]]+Geometry: ([[:digit:]]+)x([[:digit:]]+)$/width=\1\nheight=\2/p'
```

Answer (score 1):

We implement hashes in sed using GNU version of the sed editor in extended regex mode `-E`

```
fmt=',x=%d\ny=%d\nxwidth=%d\nheight=%d'
sed -En '
  1{x;s/.*/'"$fmt"'/;x;}
  /Position:|Geometry:/G
  s/.*\s([0-9]+)([x,])([0-9]+)\s.*\n\2([^=]+=)%d([^=]+=)%d.*/\4\1\5\3/p
' file
x=5
y=279
width=960
height=480
```

---

Another method is using python and nested list comprehension:

```
python3 -c 'import sys
## separator based on first field
s = { "Position:" : ",",
      "Geometry:" : "x" }

## string format based on first field
f = { "Position:" : "x={}\ny={}",
      "Geometry:" : "width={}\nheight={}" }

with open(sys.argv[1]) as fh:
  print(*[f[f0].format(*(f1.split(s[f0]))) for l in fh for f0,f1 in [l.strip().split()[0:2]] if f0 in f],sep="\n")
' file
```